# AngularJS - using data binding {{}} in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, single-page-application, angularjs-ng-click

Is there a way to change the method called by ng-click dynamically?

Something like this:

```
ng-click = "{{functionCalled}}"
```

and then declaring the function by:

```
$scope.functionCalled = "callThisFunction(param)";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick), ngClick just evaluates the expression in the context of the scope. There's nothing stopping you from referencing a function dynamically, but I'm not sure this is the intended method. I would probably call a function explicitly and switch the behavior based on a parameter instead like `ng-click='myFunction(myParams)'`. Nonetheless, here's an example of what you what to accomplish. http://jsfiddle.net/8cvGt/2/

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app='foo' ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <div ng-click='this[myVar]()'>{{ bar }}</div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('foo',[]).controller('ctrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = 'callIt';
    $scope.bar = 'before';
    $scope.callIt = function() {
        $scope.bar = 'after';
    }
});
```

Comment: Great it works thanks, however is there a way I can dynamically set a parameter too? say for a function callit(callId) ?

Comment: Sure, just add your paramater to your call. `this[myFunc](myParam)`

Comment: I mean so that the parameter takes the value of an ng-model element form the view, such as  <input id="inputAns" type="text" data-ng-model="quiz.ans1"></input>

Comment: doing it the way you mentioned inputs a parameter value "quiz.ans1" rather than its actual value

Comment: Do you have a functioning example of this? Unless you're calling it with `this[myFunc]('quiz.ans1')` it shouldn't be using the variable name.

Comment: I updated the fiddle with the scenario I think you're talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/8cvGt/5/

Comment: I need to set the parameter in the controller so I am doing $scope.myParam = 'quizAns1';  I don't know how else to do it

Comment: Oh I see. You'll have to reference quizAns1 some other way then. I assume you're doing this in some sort of loop which is why you're doing it dynamically in the first place?

Comment: Oh ok. No the button clicked is a 'done' button on the right side of the navigation bar (as there are in apps) and it is on the index page, outside of the ng-view. I want the button to be changed depending on which view I am in, therefore I am using $rootScope to change the button value from each individual controller

Comment: probably a very bad way of doing it

Comment: Hmm, yeah I probably wouldn't use this to accomplish that use case. Either a dynamically determined partial for each view `ng-include='myViewVariable + "button_section.html"'`, expand the view to include that section, or have a consistent API between views that it can call like `ng-click='done()'` and the done function determine what parameters it needs. Hard to tell which is appropriate without knowing more about the app.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a set list of possible functions, use a central function to dispatch calls to other functions.

```
ng-click="dispatchFunction(param)"
```

Then

```
$scope.functionToCall = 'callThisFunction';

$scope.dispatchFunction = function(param) {
    switch($scope.functionToCall) {
         case (callThisFunction): callThisFunction(param);
    };
```

**Edit**: Actually, use a full dispatch table for this:

http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/using-dispatch-tables-to-avoid-conditionals-in-javascript